# execute the global variable generation part of a library in an executable project

Tags: c++, global-variables, static-libraries

My application is consists of two projects which one of them create the executable file and the other generates the library that executable is going to use. I have tested the library before using some Main test. There are some global variable definitions in the library project which should be executed (to create some default options) before my executable project started to work. For example in my library project, I have code like this:

```
const ifxFactoryProductInitializerNew<ifxComplexResultContainer, ifxResultContainer<1, ifxComplexVector3f> > fp_r1("1");
const ifxFactoryProductInitializerNew<ifxComplexResultContainer, ifxResultContainer<2, ifxComplexVector3f> > fp_r2("2");
const ifxFactoryProductInitializerNew<ifxComplexResultContainer, ifxResultContainer<3, ifxComplexVector3f> > fp_r3("3");
```

How can I use this library while the global part of it executes before my executable projects run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I look for it, it is not possible.

I have to put the global definitions in a function and call that function in the beginning of the executable project.